# Как сравнить даты между собой

Tags: php

Как сравнить даты между собой (например даны даты 4.11.2017, 7.11.2017, 23.02.2017) необходимо их сравнить с датой 4.11.2017.

Comment: В каком виде даты даны? Строкой, небось?

Comment: да в виде строк

Answer (score 1):

```
private function compareDate(\DateTime $a, \DateTime $b): bool
{
    return $a->format('Y-m-d') === $b->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ использовать strtotime(), например

```
if (strtotime('4.11.2017') == strtotime('7.11.2017')) {
    echo "Они совпадают!";
}
```

не нравятся функции, используйте объект DateTime, например

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('7.11.2017');
var_dump($datetime1 == $datetime2);
```

Comment: Если 4.11.2017 совпало с одной из дат ( даты: 4.11.2017, 7.11.2017, 23.02.2017) как вывести сообщение об совпадении??

Comment: Есть `if(condition) {вывести сообщение}`. Например `if (strtotime('4.11.2017') == strtotime('7.11.2017')) {echo 'Они совпадают';}`

Comment: if (strtotime('4.11.2017') == strtotime('7.11.2017')) {echo 'Они совпадают';} поидее это не выполняется, значит ничего не должно выводиться, а он выводит, что они совпадают

Comment: Попробовал код - все ок. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8a0b460e2337d7f99d27a685300414208d11e088

Comment: да там работает, а в АПАЧ не работает данная команда почему-то. Есть ли альтернатива этой команде?

Comment: я в ответе про DateTime писал и пример приводил

Answer (score 0):

Сравнение дат (именно сравнение, а не равенство)

[DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php)